# Error installing Apache Cloudstack management on Ubuntu 16.0.4

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I am installing Apache cloudstack on ubuntu 16.0.4, but after installing cloudstack setup when I start services of cloudstack management service it displayed the following errors. (I have installed tomcat7, but tomcat 6 is not installed)

> **Warning: cloudstack-management.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units. Job for
>   cloudstack-management.service failed because the control process
>   exited with error code. See "systemctl status
>   cloudstack-management.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.**

I have checked `systemctl status cloudstack-management.service` command and it displays the following:

```
cloudstack-management.service - LSB: Start Tomcat (CloudStack).
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cloudstack-management; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-08-25 21:53:07 IST; 1min 11s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 26684 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cloudstack-management start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Aug 25 21:53:07 dhaval-pc systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat (CloudStack)....
Aug 25 21:53:07 dhaval-pc cloudstack-management[26684]:  * cloudstack-management is not installed
Aug 25 21:53:07 dhaval-pc systemd[1]: cloudstack-management.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 25 21:53:07 dhaval-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Tomcat (CloudStack)..
Aug 25 21:53:07 dhaval-pc systemd[1]: cloudstack-management.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 25 21:53:07 dhaval-pc systemd[1]: cloudstack-management.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Warning: cloudstack-management.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

What change can I make in `vi /etc/init.d/cloudstack-management` file?